# How to find all internal ranges in a specified range

Tags: excel, vba, foreach, range

How do I find all the internal name ranges that are within a specified range?

For example, there are three ranges: R_1, R_2 and R_3.
[image]

In this example, the specified range is R_2.
I need to find R_2 and R_3.

```vb
Dim nm As Name

For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
  *** CODE HERE ***
Next nm
```

I previously used the following code.

```vb
Dim nm As Name
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range("R_2")  'specified range

For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
    If Not Intersect(rng,Range(nm)) Is Nothing Then
        *** CODE HERE ***
    End If
Next nm
```

It worked if I needed to find all internal ranges, but no external ranges existed.
That is, if there was no range R_1, I would have no problem finding R_2 and R_3 but if there is an external range, then searching for intersections is not appropriate.

The names of ranges can be different, so I need exactly the enumeration of all ranges (for each).

---

On the basis of the suggested answers, I formed a solution:

```vb
Sub Test()
Dim nm As Name
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range("R_2") 'example specified range

For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
    If nm.RefersToRange.Parent.Name = ActiveSheet.Name Then 'ranges only from the active sheet
        If isInside(rng, nm) And Not rng.Name = nm Then Debug.Print nm.Name
    End If
Next nm

End Sub


Function isInside(rb As Range, ra As Excel.Name) As Boolean
Dim r As Range
   
Set r = Intersect(ra.RefersToRange, rb)

If Not r Is Nothing Then
    isInside = (ra.RefersToRange.Cells.CountLarge = r.Cells.CountLarge)
    Exit Function
End If

End Function
```

In my project, this code accomplishes the task, even if there are ranges that are contiguous with boundaries.

Second example image:
[image]

Comment: If the intersect between the named range and the specified range has the same number of cells as the named range, then the named range is completely contained in the specified range.  Note before running Intersect you need to check both ranges are on the same worksheet.

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, I understand that. And I have a check for the location of ranges on the same sheet. I just decided not to specify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the names of the named areas you need a secure loop. From the heart of the loop, the function that does the checking is called. Checks if the number of cells of the intersection of the two regions is equal to the cells of the checked region. If so, then the controlled region is entirely within our original region.

```
Public Function getInnerRanges(specificRange As String) As String
   Dim nRng As Name, r As Range, rng As Range
   Set rng = Range(specificRange)
   getInnerRanges = specificRange
   For Each nRng In ThisWorkbook.Names
      If specificRange <> nRng.Name Then
         If isInside(rng, nRng) Then
            getInnerRanges = getInnerRanges & "," & nRng.Name
         End If
      End If
   Next
End Function

Public Function isInside(rb As Range, ra As Excel.Name) As Boolean
   Dim r As Range
   On Error GoTo Lerr
   Set r = Intersect(ra.RefersToRange, rb)
   If Not r Is Nothing Then
      isInside = (ra.RefersToRange.Cells.CountLarge = r.Cells.CountLarge)
      Exit Function
   End If
   On Error GoTo 0
   Exit Function
Lerr:
   On Error GoTo 0
   isInside = False
End Function

Sub example22()
   Dim s As String
   s = getInnerRanges("R_2")
   Debug.Print s
End Sub
```

Comment: The principle of the function `isInside` turned out to be the most elegant solution in my case. The only thing, please tell me, why there are so many error checks? The code works without them too, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: There is only one error check, not many! This is necessary because a) in the book there may be NAMED RANGES referring to different sheets while Intersect accepts parameters belonging to the same sheet b) In the same sheet there may be "NAMED RANGES" that are not ranges... e.g a named range with name ZERO having reference to: =0 . So to avoid errors we would have to do a lot of checks before sending the parameters to Intersect and the easiest way to avoid the checks is to trap the errors.

Comment: In an update to the post, I pointed out that there is a check for the same sheet. But I didn't know about the ranges from point b). In my project they are excluded, but it is useful knowledge. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the coordinates of the corners it is quite easy to compare. The first method tests all ranges against all ranges. The last method calculates the values.
You will have to decide if it should compare with < and > or <= and >=.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim nm1 As Name, nm2 As Name
    
    For Each nm1 In ThisWorkbook.Names
        For Each nm2 In ThisWorkbook.Names
            If nm1.Name <> nm2.Name Then
                Debug.Print nm1.Name & " inside of " & nm2.Name & ": " & IsInside(nm1.RefersToRange, nm2.RefersToRange)
            End If
        Next nm2
    Next nm1
End Sub

Function IsInside(InnerRange As Range, OuterRange As Range) As Boolean
    Dim InnerLeft As Long
    Dim InnerTop As Long
    Dim InnerRight As Long
    Dim InnerBottom As Long
    Dim OuterLeft As Long
    Dim OuterTop As Long
    Dim OuterRight As Long
    Dim OuterBottom As Long
    
    With InnerRange
        InnerTop = .Row
        InnerLeft = .Column
        InnerBottom = .Row + .Rows.Count
        InnerRight = .Column + .Columns.Count
    End With
    With OuterRange
        OuterTop = .Row
        OuterLeft = .Column
        OuterBottom = .Row + .Rows.Count
        OuterRight = .Column + .Columns.Count
    End With
    IsInside = False
    If InnerLeft > OuterLeft And InnerRight < OuterRight Then
        If InnerTop > OuterTop And InnerBottom < OuterBottom Then
            IsInside = True
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I replaced the comparison with < and > in the function on <= and >=. Because some ranges in my project can touch the boundaries. And it worked. Thanks for the help!